# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf 3.0.0.RELEASE integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem, when I try integrate Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE and Thymeleaf 3.0.0.Release. I know that Spring Boot now support Thymeleaf 3 version so I try workaround this problem like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
```

and add my own SpringWebConfig configuration.
unfortunately received error like this :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.IResourceResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/resourceresolver/IResourceResolver



wrapped by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration due to org/thymeleaf/resourceresolver/IResourceResolver not found. M                                                                                                        ake sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
```

Comment: Spring Boot 1.3 doesn't support (according to you it does or your wording is off then please change your question). Also add the full stack trace not only a snippet as well as your configuration.

Answer (score 17):

It's much simpler, just read this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: You might also want to add <thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>

Answer (score 3):

spring boot 1.4.0 + thymeleaf 3.0.1

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please also add some explanation of how the above code solves the problem.

Comment: This has helped. The case: Spring Boot is used as a POM-import dependency, not the parent POM.

Comment: Better use the properties of Henrique's answer

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the documentation for 1.4.7.RELEASE: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3

---

If you use Gradle put this in the build.gradle file:

**Gradle: build.gradle**

```
ext['thymeleaf.version'] = '3.0.2.RELEASE'
ext['thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version'] = '2.1.1'
```

---

If you use Maven put this in the pom.xml file:

**Maven: pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

---

(since I have not enough reputation, I posted an answer instead of a comment on one of the previous answers. Especially the build.gradle part.)

Answer (score 1):

For Maven project just add following line on pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

For gradle project create a gradle.properties file with following contents

```
thymeleaf.version=3.0.2.RELEASE
thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version=2.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Spring Boot 1.3.3 working with Thymeleaf 3 using this Configuration class. I recall having to work to get around that same exception. Also, ThymeleafAutoConfiguration is excluded in my autoscan setup, like it is in yours.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ThymeleafProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnClass(SpringTemplateEngine.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)

public class ThymeleafConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    ThymeleafProperties properties;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.addTemplateResolver(urlTemplateResolver());
        engine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        // pre-initialize the template engine by getting the configuration.  It's a side-effect.
        engine.getConfiguration();
        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCacheable(properties.isCache());
        return resolver;
    }

    private UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver() {
        return new UrlTemplateResolver();
    }

}
```

(The resolver.setPrefix, resolver.setSuffix, and resolver.setTemplateMode may not be necessary anymore, but they were with the first beta release.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help,
I am a little confused by this configuration and integration Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. But the problem remains.... Temporarily in the target project back to a previous version thymeleaf. Below a link to a proof on concept of this solution. There is a full configuration and dependencies. [link] https://github.com/przodownikR1/voteEngine

Answer (score 0):

**Do the simply step by step**

**1. adding dependency for thymeleaf.**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**2. adding dependency for thymeleaf dialect.**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**3. SpringBoot autoconfiguration for thymeleaf**

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true 
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true 
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/html/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.reactive.max-chunk-size=0
```