# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.dialect.IExpressionEnhancingDialect

Tags: thymeleaf, jhipster

I am running **jhipster** application as **JavaApplication**, but I'm receiving error message. I have tried with all the solutions, but unable to run the application successfully. I also searched for the class `IExpressionEnhancingDialectin` in jar `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.2.1.2.RELEASE.jar`, but couldn't find it.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough details to get help. Which version of JHipster? Which configuration? Current version of JHipster uses Thymeleaf only for templating e-mail messages, so what have you done? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in the pom file worked for me:

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

Taken from the most rated answer here:
[Spring Boot and Thymeleaf 3.0.0.RELEASE integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439369/spring-boot-and-thymeleaf-3-0-0-release-integration)